# match and replace vs manual editing

Tags: html, regex, search, replace

I have a few HTML pages in which I use `<sup></sup>` tags.

I want to add `acronym`s to these, *e.g*:

`<sup><acronym title="united states of america">USA</acronym></sup>`.

There are few hundred pages with different `<sup></sup>` tags that I want to replace. My question is if I used `.match()` and/or `.replace()` in JavaScript and create a function that does it for me would I be too taxing for the load time of page. I have heard that regex and other search and replace text slows down the load time of the page. Would it be better to do it this way or should I just edit in manually on each page.

Comment: thanks for editing I could not make it appears as code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean all pages that now have `<sup></sup` should be changed to contain the acronym, I see no reason to do that dynamically in Javascript. It's a static change. If you use an editor that can make global changes in multiple files, that would be basically only one action.

Unless there are conditions that you forgot to mention...

Answer (score 3):

While it is true that **every DOM manipulation will add to the final rendering time of the page**, it is not easy to tell whether this specific manipulation will be noticeable for your audience.

*However*, why change the DOM on load? You should be able to automate the task and **update the source (HTML) files once and for all**.